# Using the value of a cell if blank, if not blank run this formula in excel

Tags: excel-formula

How can I put this together?

A2 has a value, say 2104

However, I need A14 to calculate if A10, A11, A12 is equal to zero/blank use A2 value if A10-A12 has a value of 1 or higher run this formula A7*A13*4.33 and use this value.

if(A10,A11,A12,"0", A2) if not use this A7*A13*4.33 as the value for A14

A13 has A10*A11*A12

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: does *"if A10, A11, A12 is equal to zero/blank"* mean if **all the values** are zero/blank or **any of the values** are zero/blank ???

Comment: If any of the values in A10-A12 are 0/blank then I need the value of A14 to equal the value in input in A2.  If A10-A12 have a value of 1 or higher I input into that cell,  then I need to run this formula:  A7*A13*4.33 and have this as the value in A14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A14** enter:

<strike>=IF(AND(A10>=0,A11>=0,A12>=0),A7*A13*4.33,A2)</strike>

**EDIT#1:**

Use this instead:

```
=IF(AND(A10>0,A11>0,A12>0),A7*A13*4.33,A2)
```

The `AND()` demands that **all** the tested cells be above zero.  If **any** of the tested cells are zero or blank or negative, then we use **A2**

Comment: Does not work.  If I put a zero in either A10-12 then at A14 I get a blank.   It does not give me the value which is in A2 instead.

Comment: That solved it!  I just don’t understand the logic of it?

Comment: @Torn  See my added comment!

Comment: Thanks for the response   Very much appreciated!